# How can I modify code of all files in folders

Tags: c++, file-io

I need to make some recurrent modification in a lot of files (C++). I need to replace all strcpy() and strcat() by sprintf(). I figured out that the conversion would be made like this :

```
strcpy(out,in) would be sprintf(out,%d,in)
```

and

```
strcat(out,in) would be sprintf(out,out%d,in)
```

What tool could I use to rapidly make all replacement, I can't do it manually there is over 9000 of these to modify.

Thanks for your suggestions.

I'm using windows xp/linux Ubuntu

The reason why I do this is that we plan to implement a method that translate code. And because we are using strcat and all, we can't make a situational translating working well. Because the file where all will be written won have all the stuff in the right order

Comment: find-and-replace with reg-ex in some kind of ide?

Comment: Consider posting in [superuser.com](http://superuser.com).  I would also recommend [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed), it was made for this type of work.

Comment: [awk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) and [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) are very handy for such things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the compiler -- or, more accurately, the preprocessor.

Specifically, I'd find a project-wide header, and in it add a couple lines like:

```
#define strcpy(out, in) sprintf(out, "%s", in)
#define strcat(out, in) sprintf(out+strlen(out), "%s", in)
```

...and leave the rest of the source code alone. Then when you come to your senses, it'll be easy to change back to being sensible and using `strcpy`/`strcat` where they should be.

Comment: @Franko Just to be clear, he's telling you not to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You should use any good source editor (like notepad++) to replace strings according to regular expression. However don't forget to backup all your files in a separate location before trying to change 9k line with one expression.

Regards

Comment: "However don't forget to backup all your files in a separate location before trying to change 9k line with one expression." rather use version control.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the replacements would be:

```
strcpy(out,in) to sprintf(out, "%s", in)
```

and

```
strcat(out,in) to do{ int temp = strlen(out); sprintf(out+temp, "%s", in); } while(0)
```

Second, to make this change it depends on your operating system. If you are under Linux or macOS, or Windows with access to Linuxy tools, you could use `sed` that takes regular expressions.

In a normal windows, I don't know.

Comment: You should never use `sprintf`. Always prefer `snprintf`.

Comment: Generally yes, but if you have code that is sound (correct) using `strcpy` and `strcat`, the following conversion will also be sound, even though it doesn't have boundary checks. As a matter of fact, if you are automatically performing this conversion, you can't (at least not easily) use `sprintf` simply because you don't know the sizes of `in` and `out`.